# Is every field the residue field of a discretely valued field of characteristic 0?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields, valuation-theory, valuation-rings

Let $k$ be a field of positive characteristic $p$. Is there necessarily a discrete valuation ring of characteristic $0$ with maximal ideal $(p)$ and residue field isomorphic to $k$?

Comment: I think the right keyword is: Witt ring

Comment: @YCor a better keyword is Witt vector, since Witt ring will bring up unrelated material on the Witt ring of a quadratic form. Anyway, Witt vectors answer the question for *perfect* fields of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Oh, sure, Ring of Witt vectors (so strange name I messed it up in my mind!). But OK, I was unsure about the generality!

Comment: Depending on how restrictive you make your definition of a discrete valuation ring, you can even trivially drop the requirement that $p$ be positive (as you seem to do in your title):  if $p = 0$, then you can take the ring to be $k$, with the trivial valuation that is identically $0$ on $k^\times$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, by Hasse-Schmidt ("Die Struktur diskret bewerteter Koerper", Crelle's Journal, 1934) for any field $k$ of characteristic $p$ there exists a strict Cohen ring $A$, which is a Noetherian, complete local, discrete valuation ring with maximal ideal $pA$ and residue field $A/pA = k$. See also Mac Lane (Theorem 2 in "Subfields and automorphism groups of p-adic fields", Ann. of Math. 1939) and Cohen ("On the structure and ideal theory of complete local rings", Trans. AMS, 1946).

Comment: here is a reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08297.pdf

Comment: Title of @dodd's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378770/is-every-field-the-residue-field-of-a-discretely-valued-field-of-characteristic#comment961210_378774):  [Anscombe and Jahnke - The model theory of Cohen rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08297).